# Facebook Messenger Integration With Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook

Am trying to Integrate Salesforce Marketing cloud with Facebook Messenger with REST API as provided by the [Salesforce help doc /ott/v1/send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/OTTsendMessageToRecipient.htm).

Am getting proper response from the Postman but not getting any messages in messenger:

Step 1: Register a Facebook Page via API

[image]

Step 2: Send message via /ott/v1/send

[image]

Am getting proper response back. But couldn't able to see any message in messenger.

Any help will be much appreciated.